# Getting the list of subnet ids created with for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

How may I get the list of subnet ids created with for_each (need at the bottom of my script):

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {
  state = "available"
}

locals {
  az_names = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names
}

variable "vpc_cidr" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each                = {for idx, az_name in local.az_names: idx => az_name}
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, each.key)
  availability_zone       = local.az_names[each.key]
}

module "eks" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"

  # I need to get the list of subnet ids (aws_subnet.private) here
  subnet_ids = []
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `aws_subnet` resource was created with `for_each`, you could reference the values to create a list using `for` [1]:

```
subnet_ids = [for k, v in aws_subnet.private : aws_subnet.private[k].id]
```

Just tested with the same code you have and `terraform plan` shows no errors.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for#for-expressions

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciated if this works. :)

Comment: what if you want the list for both private and public subnets?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but I don't think you can set EKS nodes to be in public and private subnets at the same time.

Comment: ah. no i was just wondering in general, if i create public and private subnets as two different resources, how could i get a list of all subnets easily...i managed to figure it out

Comment: I guess the same way as the above, but I don't know the context. :)

Comment: yeah, in my case i used a concat to merge the two lists:
```output "subnet_ids" {
  value = concat(values(aws_subnet.public_subnets)[*].id, values(aws_subnet.private_subnets)[*].id)
}```

Answer (score 6):

While using a `for` is correct, a shorter expression would be to use [`values`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/values) function with a [`splat`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) operator:

```
subnet_ids = values(aws_subnet.private)[*].id
```

Comment: This is a great answer, hadn't thought of it!